# pasar valores desde un método a una variable objeto

Tags: java, array

Tengo el siguiente código y no sé cómo hacer que los valores de la matriz se almacenen en la variable vector de forma global para poder trabajar con el vector en otros métodos. Por lo que veo con el primer print, sí obtiene los datos de matriz[][]. Pero en el segundo print no tiene los datos. Lo que quiero es almacenar los datos de matriz en la variable vector.

Las variables matriz[][], filas y columnas reciben valores de otros métodos.

```
private int matriz [][];
private int filas;
private int columnas;

private int vector[];

public void construyeVector() {
    this.vector =new int[columnas*filas];
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        for(int i2=0;i2<columnas;i2++) {
            int j=1;
            vector[j]=matriz[i][i2];
            System.out.print(vector[j]+" ");
            j+=1;
        }
    }
    for(int l= 0; l<vector.length;l++) {
        System.out.print(vector[l]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende: *Pero en el segundo print, fuera de los bucles for no tiene los datos*  No veo ningún print fuera de bucles `for`. Hay dos print, cada uno dentro de un bucle.  Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y aclara qué es lo que pasa, y dónde pasa. Gracias.

Comment: Espero que así quede más claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int matriz [][];
private int filas;
private int columnas;

private ArrayList<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<>();

public void construyeVector() {

    for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++) {
        for(int i2=0;i2<matriz[i].length;i2++) { 
            this.vector.add(matriz[i][i2]); 
        }
    }
    for(int l= 0; l< this.vector.size();l++) {
        System.out.print(this.vector.get(l));
    }
}
```

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo y será por lo poco que sé pero no me funciona. Me da distintos errores que no sé como arreglar. Igualmente te agradezco la respuesta.

Comment: qué errores te da ?

Comment: 1. En la definición de la variable en <int> me dice que debo insertar las dimensiones. 2. Me da error en un constructor que está inmediatamente debajo de la definición de la variable vector.Solo tiene el modificador public y me dice que solo puede tener un modificador. Y por último me dice que "vector" no puede ser resuelto o no es un campo.

Comment: ya está,perdón.

Comment: Ahora sí funciona, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si esta respuesta te sirvió, dale ^ y flecha verde, eso me ayuda a mí, recuerda que el array guarda numéricos, si necesitas otro tipo de dato cambia a String o a clases hechas por ti.

Comment: Deberías por lo menos agregar más explicación al código, es decir, porqué resuelve el problema y de este modo, mejoras la calidad de la respuesta.